# isset не работает

Tags: php, ajax, post

не выполняется условие с isset. статус с браузере 200, и все данные передаются. Jquery подключен. В чем же может быть ошибка?

````js
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {mon: choosenMon, sub: choosenSub},
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.status);
        },
        error: function(response){
            alert(response.status);
        }
    });



if(isset($_POST['mon'])){
    $mon = $_POST['mon'];
    $sub = $_POST['sub'];
    translate($mon);
    dataPrinting($mon);
        studentsPrinting();
}
```




<!-- end snippet -->
````

Comment: А как вы статус меняете? Я собственно тут не вижу изменений статуса он у вас всегда будет 200 запрос доставлен

Comment: @vp_arth почему, в данном случае как раз просто так попадет, это ответ надо  отдавать в json, вроде как.

Comment: @vp_arth я уже тоже засомневался) проверил - все верно, если в `$.ajax` указан `type: "POST"`, то данные из `data: {...} ` попадают сразу в `$_POST`

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Он действительно [шлёт просто форму](https://jsfiddle.net/vp_arth/zgyu25Ls/) Стало быть я ошибся в jquery, бывает) Удалю лишнее из комментов